# Translate specific phases in a string in elixir

Tags: string, elixir, gettext

I have a list with words that needs to be translated in strings, but not the whole string should be translated, only the words that is in the list.

a example

```
list_with_words_that_needs_to_translate = ["here", "with one", "a string"]
```

the strings that should be partly translated;

```
"here is a string", 

"word with one and two",

"and something that doesn't need translate"
```

and the expected result would be:

```
"here is a string" -> ["here", "is", "a string"] 
"word with one and two" -> ["word", "with one", "and two"]
```

so I can send the pieces to a func that translate them, returns them and the and `Enum.join` to get the new translated string.

The words will be translated to multible langs with gettext so I can't use `String.replace` and since the word-strings in the list has spaces in them I can't split on space.

Any pieces of advice?

Comment: `"word with one and two" -> ["word", "with one", "and two"]` -> sure? There is no "and two" on the list. Shouldn't it be `["word", "with one", "and", "two"]`

Comment: @Grych, sure or not, it doesn't matter, I'm only after the words in the list, how the other ones are split could be anyway as long as they are there so I can join the string back together after translating the word in the list.

Comment: Can't you throw them into a map function? list_with_words_that_needs_to_translate |>  Enum.map(&(gettext(&1))) |> Enum.join

Comment: Have you thought about whether the order of the fragments will be the same for every language? I've come across this problem recently and solved it with gettext translations on two levels, i.e. first grab the fragments `here = gettext("here"); a_string = gettext("a string")`, and then interpolate them into the final string: `gettext("%{here} is %{a_string}", here: here, a_string: a_string)`. This way you could override the final template for a specific language if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use reduce to apply some function to every found word. Here is the example with `String.upcase/1`:

```
iex(17)> tr = fn s1 -> list_with_words |> Enum.reduce(s1, fn(x, acc) -> 
                String.replace(acc, x, String.upcase(x)) end) 
              end

iex(18)> tr.("here is a string")
"HERE is A STRING"
iex(19)> tr.("word with one and two")
"word WITH ONE and two"
iex(20)> tr.("and something that doesn't need translate")
"and something that doesn't need translate"
```